# Operators on a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Problem 17 of section 3.D in Linear Algebra Done Right:

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $E$ is a subspace of $L(V)$ such that $ST\in E$ and $TS\in E$ for all $S\in L(V)$ and all $T\in E$. Prove that $E={0}$ or $E=L(V)$.

I found a solution [here](http://linearalgebras.com/3D.html), but would like a better explanation if possible. I'm especially lost on the $E_{ij}$ operators.

Comment: Have you already learned some ring theory, ideals, etc.?

Comment: Nope, would that help?

Comment: The $E_{ij}$ are the maps that map the $i$th basis vector to the $j$th basis vector, and map everything else to $0$. The corresponding matrix would have only $0$s except in the $i$th row and the $j$th column, where it has a $1$.

Comment: So is "$\delta_{ii}=0$" a typo? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes, that should be 1

Comment: That'd help a lot, but it'd make this exercise too easy...anyway, have you seen the relation (isomorphism, in fact) between operators and square matrices?

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm not sure if this is the extent of what you mean, but I do see that operators must be square matrices.

Comment: Ok, that's good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that, if $E\ne\{0\}$, then $E$ contains the identity operator, because then the property about products implies $E=L(V)$.

Suppose $E\ne\{0\}$. Then there are $T\in E$ and $w\in V$ such that $T(w)=v\ne0$.

Complete $v$ to a basis of $V$, $\{v=v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$.

For $i=1,\dots,n$ let $S_i$ be the operator such that $S_i(v_1)=v_i$ and $S_i(v_k)=0$ for $k=2,\dots,n$. Let also $S'_i$ be the operator such that $S'_i(v_i)=w$ and $S'_i(v_k)=0$, for $k\ne i$.

By assumption, $T_{i}=S_iTS'_i\in E$. Moreover
$$
T_i(v_i)=S_iTS'_i(v_i)=S_iT(w)=S_i(v_1)=v_i
$$
and, if $k\ne i$,
$$
T_i(v_k)=S_iTS'_i(v_k)=0
$$
The operator $T_1+T_2+\dots+T_n$ is the identity and it belongs to $E$, which is closed under sums.

---

The result is false as soon as $V$ is not finite dimensional. Indeed, consider the subspace of $L(V)$ consisting of the operators having finite dimensional range. This satisfies the required properties and is not the same as $L(V)$.

Answer (score 1):

Same method, slightly reduced (but I don't think you can go much below, in a proof 'by hand'):

Let $(e_i)$ be a basis and $(\ell_j)$ a dual basis, i.e. $\ell_j(e_i)=\delta_{ij}$ (Kronecker delta). Suppose $T\in E$ is non-trivial and maps $x\neq 0$ to $y=Tx\neq 0$. Define $S_i\in L(V)$ by 
$$ S_i(u) = x \; \ell_i(u) $$
Let $\tilde{S}_i \in L(V)$ be any map that maps $y$ to $e_i$. Then
$$ M_{ii}=\tilde{S}_i T S_i (e_j) = \tilde{S}_i T (x) \delta_{ij} = \tilde{S}_i (y) \delta_{ij}=e_i \delta_{ij} $$
Each $M_{ii}\in E$, whence also their sum, which is the identity: $M (e_j) = \sum_i M_{ii} (e_j) = e_j $.
It follows that  $E=L(V)$.

Remark: In infinite dimension the proof no longer works and the result is false: The set of compact operators $K(H)$ of a Hilbert space $H$ is a closed two sided ideal in $L(H)$ which is a proper subset when $H$ has infinite dimension.